# How to get dplyr::summarize_all to work on a sparkdataframe using databricks?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, databricks

## Question

I have a massive Spark Dataframe, called x. I am using databricks. x is billions of records long, too large to collect onto a single machine. What do I have to do to get this to work?:

```
dplyr::summarize_all(x,mean)
```

### More Info

This is the error message I currently get:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "SparkDataFrame"
```

and

```
class(x)
```

returns:
[1] "SparkDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "SparkR"

The book, [Mastering Spark with R](https://therinspark.com/analysis.html#import) , has an example of loading up a tiny r data frame, and running summarize_all on it:

```
cars <- copy_to(sc, mtcars)
summarize_all(cars, mean)
```

Note the above code works on my databricks cluster and returns a nice block of text:

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 11]
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  20.1  6.19  231.  147.  3.60  3.22  17.8 0.438 0.406  3.69  2.81
```

The same book leads me to believe I can use this and similar functions on huge spark dataframes.

and also

```
class(cars)
```

returns:

```
[1] "tbl_spark" "tbl_sql"   "tbl_lazy"  "tbl"
```

It seems obvious that I need to convert my spark dataframe to a tbl_spark, tbl_sql, tbl_lazy or tbl so that I can pass it to dplyr::summarize_all, but I have searched all over the place and asked experts and cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/R/as.data.frame.html ?

Comment: marsei, the documentation you linked to for as.data.frame says "... downloads the contents of a SparkDataFrame into an R's data.frame. Since data.frames are held in memory, ensure that you have enough memory in your system..." Please note in my question I said that x is a massive sparkdataframe that will not fit on a single system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that `SparkR` and `sparklyr` are different APIs that don't play well together. You can convert the `SparkR` data frame to be used with `sparklyr` by using a temp table.

Here's an example `SparkR` data frame.

```
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method = "databricks")

x_sparkr <- SparkR::sql("SELECT 1 AS a UNION SELECT 2")
```

Create the temp table.

```
SparkR::registerTempTable(x_sparkr, "temp_x")
```

Load it into `sparklyr`.

```
x_sparklyr <- dplyr::tbl(sc, "temp_x")

dplyr::summarize_all(x_sparklyr, mean)
#> # Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
#>       a
#>   <dbl>
#> 1   1.5
```

Comment: Paul, the part I was missing was dplyr::tbl(sc, "temp_x") ! I tested this on my production system with real data it works! So happy about this!